# nearest lat and long in SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi so my problem is iv creating an android project which gets the user current latitude and longitude and then gives them there wind speed at that location using a SQLite database.

My database is made of 4 columns which are all string values, where 1st column is ID, second is WindSpeed, third is Longitude and fourth is Latitude.

What my problem is, i need to find the nearest location to the user current location in the database, ive asked a question on this previously and had a answer but im unsure a if its correct and b if its implemented correctly if so what am i doing wrong because im completely stuck and beginning to panic

I think the problem may lie in the Where clause but i could be wrong.

Here is the code

```
  public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "WindSpeedDB.sqlite";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String LAT_VAL = "Latitude";
private static final String LONG_VAL = "Longitude";
private static final String WIND_SPEED = "WindSpeed";
private static final String ROW_ID=     " ID";
double Lat=   52.9318635;
double Long=  0.6692808;
public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}




    public Double getWindSpeed2(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String [] sqlSelect = {WIND_SPEED,LAT_VAL,LONG_VAL}; 
        String sqlTables = "WindSpeed";
        String whereClause = " ? BETWEEN "+LAT_VAL+" - 1 and "+LAT_VAL+" + 1 and ?     BETWEEN "+LONG_VAL+" - 1 and "+LONG_VAL+" + 1";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] {
                String.valueOf(Lat),
                String.valueOf(Long)};

        qb.setTables(sqlTables);

        Cursor d = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null);

     Double wind_speed= 0.0;
     double min_distance=999999;

     if (d != null && d.moveToFirst()){
          double lat_v=Double.parseDouble(d.getString(2));
          double long_v=Double.parseDouble(d.getString(3));
          double dis=Math.sqrt( (lat_v-Lat)*(lat_v-Lat) + (long_v-Long)*(long_v-Long)   );
          if (dis<min_distance){

            wind_speed=Double.parseDouble(d.getString(1));
          }
        }

        return wind_speed;
   }

    }
```

the problem is this is always giving me a result of 0.0 which i believe its passing a null value at wind speed and thus its not finding the value in the database even though the value for lat and long im using is one in the database and so should give the wind speed at that spot.

Any help would be much appreciated as im ridiculously stuck!

Comment: Don't store numbers as strings. Which of the two functions are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry i never meant to include the first funtion, the function that i am using is the getWindSpeed2, i will edit my post to delete the first function to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

The cursor's column access functions use a zero-based index; you must read columns 0, 1, and 2.

The cursor might return multiple rows; replace the `if` with `while`.

Never store numbers as strings; in comparisons, strings are larger than any number.

`query` never returns `null`; you can drop the `d != null` check.

Comment: This doesnt seem to solve to problem, i think the problem could be the where statement i think checking to see whether the current latitude and longitude is betwen lat or long -0.1 and +0.1 when it should be the other way round.